# OAS And spouse's allowance

Tags: canada, pension

I just turned 64 three months ago and am currently receiving spouse's allowance. Can I submit the OAS application now or should I wait?

Answer (score 2):

You should have received a letter from Service Canada by now. If you didn't then read here:

http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/oas/apply.page

> ### The month after you turned 64 years old, you received from Service Canada
>
> A letter informing you that you could be eligible for the Old Age
>   Security (OAS) pension
>
> - you will need to apply for your OAS pension as soon as possible by completing and mailing the application form enclosed in your letter
>
> A letter informing you that you were selected for automatic enrolment
>
> - you will not have to apply for your OAS pension provided that the information in your letter is accurate.
>
> If you wish to defer your OAS pension you may do so by:
>
> - Accessing your My Service Canada account and following the directions, or
> - Signing and returning the automatic enrolment letter by mail.
>
> ### The month after you turned 64 years old, you did not receive a letter from Service Canada
>
> If you wish to start receiving your Old Age Security (OAS) pension at
>   age 65, you should apply for your OAS pension right away.
>
> - If you have already reached 65, and you wish to start your OAS 
>     pension immediately, you should apply as soon as possible so you don't
>     lose any payments (we may be able to give you a retroactive payment
>     for up to a maximum of 11 months from the date we receive your
>     application).

Comment: Thanks. So far I have not received any letter from Service Canada.